# Pick out excel cells from a long horizontal list based on an adjacent numerical value

Tags: vba, excel

I've already written this macro that does exactly what I want it to do. However, it's quite large, and I may wish to expand on it in future. Basically, the purpose is to copy and paste items from a horizontal list (where RNG is equal to the number of items there), and take one cell from each. Any suggestions in cutting this down? It feels as if there should be a way, since so little changes from line to line.

```
Sub Test()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim i As Long
i = 3
While i <= 300
    Set Rng = Range("J" & i)
    If Rng = 0 Then
        i = i + 1
    ElseIf Rng = "" Then
        i = i + 1
    ElseIf Rng = 1 Then
        i = i + 1
    ElseIf Rng = 2 Then
        Rng.Offset(, -9).Resize(, 125).Copy
        Rng.Offset(, -9).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        i = i + 2
    ElseIf Rng = 3 Then
        Rng.Offset(, -9).Resize(, 125).Copy
        Rng.Offset(, -9).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Rng.Offset(, -9).Resize(, 125).Copy
        Rng.Offset(, -9).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        i = i + 3
    ElseIf Rng = 4 Then
        Rng.Offset(, -9).Resize(, 125).Copy
        Rng.Offset(, -9).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Rng.Offset(, -9).Resize(, 125).Copy
        Rng.Offset(, -9).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Rng.Offset(, -9).Resize(, 125).Copy
        Rng.Offset(, -9).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        i = i + 4
    Else
        Stop
    End If
Wend
```

Comment: You should try to edit your title to represent what the code do, not what you want in your review. The review you are looking for should be in the body of your question.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Go through a range and insert rows based on the number in a particular cell value?

Answer (score 2):

Using a `Select` will definitely shorten up your code.

```
While i <= 300
    Set Rng = Range("J" & i)
    Select Case Rng.Value
        Case 0, 1, vbNullString
            i = i + 1
        Case 2
            Rng.Offset(, -9).Resize(, 125).Copy
            Rng.Offset(, -9).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            i = i + 2
        Case 3
            Rng.Offset(, -9).Resize(, 125).Copy
            Rng.Offset(, -9).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            Rng.Offset(, -9).Resize(, 125).Copy
            Rng.Offset(, -9).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            i = i + 3

        ' etc.

    End Select
Wend
```

The next step would be to extract a method to eliminate all of the duplication. It should take in a `Range` parameter and perform your copy/insert. Basically anytime you hit Ctrl + C you should stop and write a method instead.

Answer (score 2):

You have a fair bit of duplicate code which can be extracted into another proc:

```
Private Sub CopyAndInsert(ByRef Rng As Range, numLoops As Integer)

Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To numLoops
        Rng.Offset(, -9).Resize(, 125).Copy
        Rng.Offset(, -9).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Next i

End Sub
```

You can also replace your `If ... End If` with a `Select Case` statement.

```
Sub Test()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim numLoops As Integer
i = 3

    While i <= 300
        Set Rng = Range("J" & i)

        Select Case Rng.Value
            Case 0, 1, ""
                i = i + 1
            Case 2 To 4
                numLoops = Rng.Value - 1
                CopyAndInsert Rng, numLoops
                i = i + numLoops + 1
            Case Is > 4
                ' Do you really want to use "Stop" here?
            Case Else
                ' What should happen here?
        End Select
    Wend

End Sub
```

You should also look at using `Application.ScreenUpdating` and `Application.Calculate` as ways of improving the speed at which code runs.